# Why JavaScript variables printed correctly in some sites but considered undefined in others?

Tags: javascript, variables, scope

Why JavaScript variables printed correctly in some sites but considered undefined in others?

For example, in StackOverflow webpages I can do:

```
let x = 'y';
console.log(x); // Outputs "y".
```

But in the webpages of some other sites, like in [this Duolingo exercise](https://www.duolingo.com/skill/de/Plurals/4) the `console.log` check will fail:

```
let x = 'y';
console.log(x); // Outputs "Undefined".
```

From what I've read so far I understand it has to do with scope. But it is not clear to me what type of scope, because almost always I knew only 2 scopes in JavaScript: *Global* (document-downwards), and *Function* (covering sub functions of a function as well).

It seem to do with a third scope, *Window* (Window-downwards) but it is unclear to me **why my devtool console doesn't automatically cover this one as well**, above Document and Function, in these webpages like Duolingo, where I'm having this problem.

To declare variables anyway, I tried putting my variables in IIFEs. It didn't help so I still get "undefined" for my variables, in the sites I encounter this problem. For example:

StackOverflow:

```
(()=>{
let x = 'y';
console.log(x);
})(); // Outputs "y".
```

Duolingo exercise:

```
(()=>{
let x = 'y';
console.log(x);
})(); // Outputs "undefined".
```

Why do some websites output undefined when declaring variables and what is the best method, will you say to cope with it?

Please in your answer also explain what is the reason it's this why only in some sites but not in others, and why my IIFE try failed if I set a scope for my variables arbitrarily using this IIFE.

<sub>As a JS freshman I did my best to phrase this question. Sorry if something sounds inaccurate.</sub>

Comment: Quite possible there is an over ride for `console.log` in that sites scripts to prevent you using it. Something like `console.log = function(){/* do nothing*/}`

Comment: Why would anyone do that?..

Comment: Perhaps to make it more difficult to dig into stored data

Comment: The duolingo page you linked requires a login, so I cannot reproduce.

Comment: Where exactly do you enter this code?

Comment: I run it in the particular Duolingo page I linked to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tricky question. It's because it's not the same console.log. When you're on stackoverflow if you print

```
console.log
```

You're getting something like this

```
ƒ log() { [native code] }
```

I'm printing function definition without invocation (parenthesis) because I want to see the definition. If you do the same thing on duolingo, you get

```
ƒ (){for(var e=[],n=0;n<arguments.length;n++)e[n]=arguments[n];(vt()||window.verbose)&&Function.prototype.apply.apply(t,[console,e])}
```

Which means that this webpage overrides console.log definition which is valid in JavaScript. You get undefined because each function in JS by default returns undefined and REPL (dev tools) prints this output to you.